# Why is NLTK's PoS tagger tagging for each letter in a word instead of tagging for each word?

Tags: python, string, nlp, nltk, part-of-speech

Say I have this sentence: `I am a boy`. I want to find out the Part of Speech of each word in the sentence. This is my code:

```
import nltk
sentence = 'I am a good boy'
for word in sentence:
    print(word)
    print(nltk.pos_tag(word))
```

But this produces the following output:

```
I
[('I', 'PRP')]

[(' ', 'NN')]
a
[('a', 'DT')]
m
[('m', 'NN')]

[(' ', 'NN')]
a
[('a', 'DT')]

[(' ', 'NN')]
g
[('g', 'NN')]
o
[('o', 'NN')]
o
[('o', 'NN')]
d
[('d', 'NN')]

[(' ', 'NN')]
b
[('b', 'NN')]
o
[('o', 'NN')]
y
[('y', 'NN')]
```

So, I tried to do this instead:

```
sentence = 'I am a good boy'
for word in sentence.split(' '):
    print(word)
    print(nltk.pos_tag(word))
```

And this produces the following output:

```
I
[('I', 'PRP')]
am
[('a', 'DT'), ('m', 'NN')]
a
[('a', 'DT')]
good
[('g', 'NN'), ('o', 'MD'), ('o', 'VB'), ('d', 'NN')]
boy
[('b', 'NN'), ('o', 'NN'), ('y', 'NN')]
```

Why is it finding the PoS for each letter instead of each word? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nltk.pos_tag` works on a list or list-like thing as an argument, and tags *each element* of that. So in your second example, it splits each string (i.e., each word) into letters, just like it split the sentence into letters in the first example. It works when you pass in the whole list you got from splitting the sentence:

```
>>> nltk.pos_tag(sentence.split(" "))
[('I', 'PRP'), ('am', 'VBP'), ('a', 'DT'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('boy', 'NN')]
```

[Per documentation](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html), you usually pass in what NLTK's tokenization returned (which is a list of words/tokens).

Answer (score 3):

In both cases you are splitting data differently. But pos_tag needs an iterable as input.

In your first case you are splitting a sentence letter by letter.

 For ex

```
sentence = "cat"
for word in sentence:
    print(word)
# 'c' , 'a', 't'
```

Then you are asking pos_tagger to find part of speech of each letter.

```
print(nltk.pos_tag(word))
```

Obviously you get part of speech tag of each letter here since each time you are giving letter as input to pos_tag().

In your second example you are splitting the sentence by words.
For example:

```
sentence = 'I am a good boy'
splitted_words = sentence.split() # you can use split() instead of split(' ') 
for word in splitted_words: 
    print(word)
# 'I', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'boy'
```

Now important point to notice that each word is iterable. 'am' is iterable, we can itreate through 'am' and we get 'a' and 'm'.
So as obvious pos_tagger gave results for letters in the words.

**How to overcome this issue:**

pos_tag() needs an iterable as argument(list,tuple etc). I would recommend you to use tokenizer() present with NLTK rather than manually splitting a sentence by spaces.
So your code should be something like this:

```
sentence = "I am a good boy"
tokenised_words = word_tokenize(sentence) # ['I', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'boy']
print(nltk.pos_tag(tokenised_words))
```

**output**

```
[('I', 'PRP'), ('am', 'VBP'), ('a', 'DT'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('boy', 'NN')]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this!  the last line in the print statement should be:  print(nltk.pos_tag(tokenised_words)) instead of print(nltk.pos_tag(text)).